# Cursor loaded with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a problem with a cursor that I load with dynamic SQL in procedure. 
My query contains a date and I have this error :

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes ; expected: DATE ; got: NUMBER

Here is my procedure :

```
create or replace procedure EMP_CURSOR (
    p_date in date,
    p_schema in varchar2
) is

    c_emp sys_refcursor;

begin

    open c_emp for
        'select ID, NAME
        from ' || DBMS_ASSERT.schema_name(p_schema) || '.EMP
        where DATE_MAJ >= ' || p_date;

    EMP (c_emp);

    exception
        when others then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQLERRM);

end;
```

And this is how I call it :

```
exec EMP_CURSOR(to_date('01/01/2015','dd/MM/yyyy'),'TEST');
```

I don't know how to pass a date for a dynamic query.
When I removed the dynamic part and I put the schema name in the query, it works fine.

Comment: What's p_dateRefresh?

Comment: @jarlh Oops sorry, it's an error in my example, I fixed it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle is implicitly converting `p_date` to a string according to your [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams147.htm#REFRN10119), because you're concatenating it to a string; you need to use [bind variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/glossary.htm#CNCPT44447), per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS629):

```
open c_emp for
 'select ID, NAME
    from ' || DBMS_ASSERT.schema_name(p_schema) || '.EMP
    where DATE_MAJ >= :1' using p_date;
```

This also gives you a lot more protection from SQL injection.